# __init__ and create a linked list in Python

Tags: python, class, linked-list, init, repr

I am pretty new to Python. Although I can do some manipulation in arrays and define a new function, it is my first time to use `class` and `__init__`. I am solving the linked list question in Python and first time to define a listed list by myself.

The code I used is as:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
        
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

LL = LinkedList()
LL.head = Node(3)
print(LL.head.data)
```

I have couple questions.

1. For class, can I consider that it as an object like `array`?
2. The meaning of `def __init__`? Can I consider it as the operation in `class_var`? E.g., for node, we assign two parameters, `data` and `next` with default values `None`, then the command `Node.data` and `Node.next` will return results. Is it similar to the `array.sum()` and `array.len()`?
3. In the `Node` we create two parameters, but in the `LinkedList`, we don't assign any parameter. However, in the statement, there is `self.head = None`. Does it create a parameter `head` with default value `None`? Why should we write it as

```
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, head = None):
    self.head = Node
```

This is the basic version. And I found another advanced version as:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def __repr__(self):
        node = self.head
        nodes = []
        while node is not None:
            nodes.append(node.data)
            node = node.next
        nodes.append("None")
        return " -> ".join(nodes)
```

1. What does the `__repr__` do here?
2. What does `' -> '.join(node)` do here?

Sorry for a long story, but I hope that I can find it out what is going on here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this seems like a strange implementation of a linked list, but I'm a physicist, not a computer scientist. As I recall, though this is a pretty standard way to implement a linked list. In the code you show there is no 'consolidated' linked list object. The linked list class just stores the head node, and each node contains it's data and the name of the next node object in the linked list. You can sort of think of this like an array, but a key difference is that an array is one object where as think linked list is a collection of separate objects linked together. This is why I feel like this is strange, since I would feel more comfortable with all the data stored in one object as opposed to just 'free-range.' There must be some benefit to this, and someone more familiar with CS might know the answer.

In terms of your other questions, the `__init__()` function is the function called when you declare a new object. It initializes the object, and is sort of like a constructor.

The command `Node.next` is not similar to `array.sum()` because the first is returning the data stored in the class variable called `next` and the second is performing an operation on an array.

For the third question, I think your `__init__()` function for the `LinkedList` class should take a Node as one of the parameters. Also, in this code:

```
LL = LinkedList()
LL.head = Node(3)
```

I don't think this is the way you are supposed to assign class variables. You should either set the head node at initialization (with the `__init__()`) or create a 'setter' function that can modify the `self.head` class variable and use that function. This code *is* what you want:

```
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, head = None):
    self.head = Node
```

except it should look like this:

```
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, head = None):
    self.head = head
```

This makes the default behaviour `self.head = None`, so if you declare a new `LinkedList` object without a head node, the head node will be empty.

The `__repr__()` function is the representation function. It's basically a function that can create a string representation of an object, except you have to determine what string representation you want for the object. For the case of this linked list, it will collect all the data at the nodes (in order) then print them out. So if my head node stores the number 5, the next node stores the number 9, and the last node stores the number 7, then applying the `__repr__()` function to the head node will return the string

```
5 -> 9 -> 7
```

The `' -> '.join(node)` takes all the items in the node array and prints them as a string with the string `->` separating each value.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @natec. I have some following question. 1. Does it mean that self.data, and self.value create a subspace to store the information within the class of Node? So they are not the same as array.min, array.max, and array.sum. 2. I still get confused about the __repr__ and .join. Would you mind explaining more? Appreciate your time and patience.